# How many threads does arangodb execute AQL query by default? Can it be promoted?

Tags: arangodb, aql

How many threads does arangodb execute AQL query by default? Can it be promoted? for example:
with profiles

```
for v,e,p in  1..3 outbound 'profiles/P152834'
relations
    prune._key=='P723672'
    OPTIONS {bfs:true, uniqueVertices:'path'}
    filter v._key=='P723672'
limit 100
return p
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment query execution is mostly single threaded. [v3.6](https://www.arangodb.com/2020/01/arangodb-3-6-release-whats-new/) introduced some limited parallelization for cluster queries; [v3.7](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/release-notes-new-features37.html#traversal-parallelization-enterprise-edition) introduces parallel traversals, but only in the Enterprise Edition.